# Create 3 curves/pipes that intersect holes in multiple objects and are equal distance from each other

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

[image: Stands for the pipes-Current]

I want to create 3 metallic rods (solid pipes) which start from the solid block on left, pass through the holes on the other two stands and a few more off-camera, and end in a similar solid block. The blocks will have a transparent acrylic/plastic material. Two rods will be towards bottom of holes, and one on top. They have to be in that arrangement because some balls have to pass through them.

[image: Crude drawing of objective]
[image: Real world object]

I can't figure out how to create such 3 curves that always stay equal distance from each other, which touching the boundaries of those circles at the same time. My best guess is a single bezier curve, which is then converted to a single object/circle, and then it is modified to have 3 pipes on its edge, but have no idea how to go about it.

Please mention steps instead of only techniques and workflow names if possible, as I am a complete beginner in modeling.

Thank you

Comment: I can't imagine that. Could you draw on this screenshot how it should look like?

Comment: I have added more images to make it clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Final

[image: final]

### Bevel for Curve (wires)

In this step you will create Bevel object for main curve.

> Changed to method Duarte Farrajota Ramos mentioned in comments.

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> ***> Curve > Circle***.
2. In **Edit Mode** select all and duplicate your **Circle** than scale it down.
3. Turn on **Snapping** and move duplicated **Circle** up.
4. Switch **Pivot Center** to **3D Cursor**.
5. Duplicate smaller **Circle** and rotate it by 120 degrees.
6. Repeat step 5. for another **Circle**.
7. Remove bigger **Circle**.

[image: wires]

### Main Curve

Here you will make **Bezier Curve** which you can manipulate as you want and it will keep your wire in place.

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> ***> Curve > Bezier***.
2. Go to **Data tab**.
3. Select **Bevel Object**.
4. Crank up **Preview Resolution**.
5. Most probably you will need to scale down your **Bevel Object**.

[image: main_curve]

### Placing Main Curve in holes

I've used a bit tedious way. Most important thing here is to have the same number of vertices in **Bezier Curve (Main)** as number of hole objects.

1. Select inner loop of hole object and place **3D Cursor** in it - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

[image: 4]

2. Select vertex from **Main Curve** and move it to **3D Cursor** - also <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

[image: 5]

3. Repeat for every hole selecting another vertices from **Main Curve**.
4. Select all vertices in **Main Curve** and <kbd>V</kbd> ***> Vector*** than <kbd>V</kbd> ***> Automatic*** to have unified handles.
5. Tweak handles to be round.

[image: 6]

Comment: This is exactly how I'd go about doing it too +1. Only thing I'd do different is probably use rotation about the 3D cursor instead, to accurately place the three circles radially equidistant

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos yeah, I have though about it after posting the answer. This way was just quicker. I have thought also about making triangle, and placing Bezier Circles on it's vertices with snap > median.

Comment: @LukeD
Thank you very much. That was very helpful. 

For some reason I couldn't adjust the vertices after snapping to cursor, which was needed in a few holes. I ended up manually moving the vertices in proper places because I needed the start of pipes to be free in air. 

One thing that I had forgotten to mention is that I need the top pipe to extend more than the bottom 2 at the start. Would that be possible?

Comment: @soslearn could you please explain a bit more what does it mean that top one should extend more? Should it be longer than the rest of them?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. 

Right now I can only do this: https://i.imgur.com/37i35Bz.png
Is it possible to have this: https://i.imgur.com/ugJUKqI.png

Comment: @soslearn I don't have ability to try it right now, but later on I will solve it. For sure it's possible to convert curve to mesh and simply delete unnecessary part but you will lose ability to have non-destructible mesh.

Comment: By converting to mesh with Alt + c ? Out of curiosity I tried that now and it might cause issues. It seems to create a very detailed mesh which might slow down my already dead-slow render times if the curve is rendered as a different object?. And it seems very difficult to select all the front faces to extrude the pipe.

Comment: @soslearn yes, exactly this way. You can control resolution of the mesh by lowering resolution of main curve and bevel curve. I've used 64 but you can set it as low as you want/need. Remember that you can change it for both curves.

Comment: @soslearn sadly I can't find any method to offset just one of the pipes. Converting it to a mesh at the end of the work is only reasonable way I can think of.